# Why leave the body?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

At the beginning of *Black Panther*, King T'Chaka kills

> his brother, T'Challa's uncle.

It later transpires that the body was left in Oakland, where

> his son Erik found it.

This was undoubtedly a major motive for the film's antagonist. So why did T'Chaka leave the body there in the first place instead of returning it to Wakanda for burial, or disposing of it in some other fashion?

Comment: Too ashamed of what he did and he just want to forget everything? may be seeing any fragment of the incident could be hurtful to T'Chaka

Answer (score 3):

As he said in the movie, this hurtful truth of him having killed his own brother was too much of a burden to carry.

Although this doesn't justify why he left the body  there and didn't bring his nephew, that was his rationale.

Comment: He actually mentions not taking his nephew back, saying that he chose not to take him (the nephew) back and get remembered of what he had done.